# Error: Invalid json: .↵ at XMLHttpRequest paypal sandbox angular 8

Tags: typescript, paypal, angular8, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use the paypal button with angular 8, but i'm having this error message when the page loads.
"Error: Invalid json: .
at XMLHttpRequest. (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={clientID}:2:47515)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3747:31)
at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3524:47)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3821:34)
at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4959:14)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4996:21)"

I really appreciate any help